# Terraform and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently trying to work why Terraform does not destroy the Elastic Beanstalk environment, along with the cloud formation stack which it is a part of.

```
module "beanstalk_app" {
  source = "../../modules/compute/beanstalk"

  stack_name = "${var.stack_name}"

  env_name = "${var.env_name}"

  app_version = "${var.app_version}"

  build_number = "${var.build_number}"

  bundle_name = "${var.bundle_name}"

  bundle_source = "${var.bundle_name}"
}    

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default" {
        name                = "${var.stack_name}-${var.env_name}-app"
        application         = "${data.terraform_remote_state.hailer.hailer_app}"
        solution_stack_name = "${var.solution_stack}"
        version_label       = "${module.beanstalk_app.version}"}
    }
```

when I run the `terraform destroy` command, this resource is not even mentioned in the output.

```
data.terraform_remote_state.db: Refreshing state...
data.terraform_remote_state.matcher: Refreshing state...
data.terraform_remote_state.hailer: Refreshing state...
data.terraform_remote_state.hailer: Refreshing state...
data.aws_route53_zone.public: Refreshing state...
data.aws_iam_policy_document.default: Refreshing state...
data.aws_acm_certificate.default: Refreshing state...
data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume: Refreshing state...

Destroy complete! Resources: 0 destroyed.
```

The Beanstalk App and CloudFormation Stack still remain in the AWS console. So if I try to re-create the stack, then I simply get errors saying resources, such as security groups still exist.

**Is the expected behaviour of Terraform destroy when related to modules, and cloud formation? Because its not really usable.**

NOTE:

- *The application version was correctly destroyed along with its s3 bucket object.*
- *There are a number of related resources, aws_iam_policy, aws_iam_role etc. which are also not picked up for destroy.*

Comment: what happens, if you manually delete the elastic beanstalk environment, then `terraform apply` again?

Comment: i've just been working through that :) it kinda works, but you have to also delete the CF stack, and also I have to use the `aws cli` to remove an instance profile, and then I had a few IAM roles to manually remove.. then `apply` works fine.

Not exactly why I chose terraform though :)

Comment: ic. That's not terraform's fault. You think terraform should discover all aws resources and take care the updates? But that's not what terraform designed for. If you really want to manage the exist resources, you can run with `terraform import` on each exist resource.

Comment: Well, I get what you're saying, but, when I declare a terraform resource, I would expect it to be able to manage it. Otherwise, what's the point of it? All books I've read strongly recommend not doing anything manually once terraform is managing a resource. Anyway, I was hoping to find out if this is the expected behaviour for beanstalk specifically. Thanks.